# Compare spatial polygons and keep or delete common boundaries in R

Tags: r, compare, geospatial, polygon, boundary

I use to plot maps of Belgium available on [GADM](https://www.gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) (select Belgium) using R.

I import and plot the outside boundary of Belgium using :

```
belgium <-readRDS("gadm36_BEL_0_sp.rds")
plot(belgium)
```

Which gives me :

[image: Map of Belgium]

I import and plot the boundaries of provinces of Belgium using :

```
provinces <-readRDS("gadm36_BEL_2_sp.rds")
plot(provinces)
```

Which gives me :

[image: Map of provinces of Belgium]

What i'm trying to have is a `dataframe` with boundaries of provinces that are NOT outside boundaries of Belgium :

[image]

I tried using `over()`, `intersect()`, etc but did not founded yet a method to do that. Several approach can be used I guess :

- substract belgium boundary to the province dataset;
- Work only in the provinces dataset and keep only commons boundaries;
- else?

Thanks if you have a solution.
Grégoire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the `sf` formatted files from that site (https://www.gadm.org/download_country_v3.html), since the `sf` package is a bit easier to deal with.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

provinces <- readRDS("gadm36_BEL_2_sf.rds")

interiors <- st_intersection(provinces) %>% 
  filter(n.overlaps > 1)

interiors

# Number of columns truncated for clarity:
#   interiors %>% select(VARNAME_2, geometry, n.overlaps)
```

> ```
> Simple feature collection with 30 features and 2 fields
> geometry type:  GEOMETRY
> dimension:      XY
> bbox:           xmin: 2.851679 ymin: 49.8004 xmax: 6.033082 ymax: 51.35568
> epsg (SRID):    4326
> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
> First 10 features:
>                                                                                                             VARNAME_2
> 1                                                                            Amberes|Antuérpia|Antwerp|Anvers|Anversa
> 2                                                                            Amberes|Antuérpia|Antwerp|Anvers|Anversa
> 3  Brussel Hoofstadt|Brusselse Hoofdstedelijke Gewest|Brüssel|Bruxelas|Région de Bruxelles-Capitale|Brussels|Bruselas
> 4                                                                                                   Limbourg|Limburgo
> 5                   Flandres Oriental|Fiandra Orientale|Flandes Oriental|Flandre orientale|East Flanders|Ost Flandern
> 6                                                                            Amberes|Antuérpia|Antwerp|Anvers|Anversa
> 7                                                                            Amberes|Antuérpia|Antwerp|Anvers|Anversa
> 8                                                                            Amberes|Antuérpia|Antwerp|Anvers|Anversa
> 9                   Flandres Oriental|Fiandra Orientale|Flandes Oriental|Flandre orientale|East Flanders|Ost Flandern
> 10                                                Brabant Flamand|Brabante Flamenco|Brabante Flamengo|Flemish Brabant
>    n.overlaps                       geometry
> 1           2 MULTILINESTRING ((5.239571 ...
> 2           2 MULTILINESTRING ((4.327078 ...
> 3           2 MULTILINESTRING ((4.403365 ...
> 4           2 MULTILINESTRING ((5.117446 ...
> 5           2 MULTILINESTRING ((4.243931 ...
> 6           3       POINT (4.994605 51.0414)
> 7           3      POINT (4.243931 51.04332)
> 8           2 MULTILINESTRING ((4.994605 ...
> 9           2 MULTILINESTRING ((3.466959 ...
> 10          2 MULTILINESTRING ((5.025736 ...
> ```

To check with a plot:

```
plot(interiors$geometry)
```

[image]

What you're doing here is looking for the spatial intersection of the provinces with every other province. Then you filter out the intersections where it's just a province overlapping itself (`n.overlaps == 1`). That way you only get the interior borders where one or more provinces touches another (`n.overlaps > 1`), but not any province alone (which would be an external border).

This is an updated version of this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761959/3330437

---

To remove the circled points (intersections of 3 provinces) in the map and dataset, you can use:

```
interiors %>% filter(!st_is(., "POINT"))
```

Comment: That's just ... perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: Just to complete, for levels 3 (Districts) and 4 (Municipalities), dowloaded at the same adress, i also had to remove MULTIPOINT in addition to POINT.
And then, to not having to load sf in addition to sp, i used as(object,"Spatial") to transform the sf object in a sp compliant object, before saving de data in RDS file.