# Keep polygons that are fully or partially within a larger one without a negative buffer

Tags: r, r-sf

I'd like to keep the census tracts that comprise a larger census geography. The tracts should fit within the larger geography perfectly.

I can do this with a negative buffer, but is there a better way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tidycensus)
library(tigris)
library(tmap)

balt <- places("Maryland",
               year = 2018,
               class = "sf") %>% 
  filter(NAME == "Baltimore") %>% 
  st_transform(4326)

balt_tracts <- get_acs(geography = "tract",
                       variables = "B01003_001E", # population
                       year = 2018,
                       state = "Maryland",
                       survey = "acs5",
                       geometry = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(4326)

balt_tracts %>% 
  .[st_within(st_buffer(., -0.001),  
              balt) %>% lengths > 0,] %>% 
  qtm()
```

[image]

An intersection returns tracts outside the larger geography that share an edge, which I don't want.

```
balt_tracts[balt,] %>% 
  qtm()
```

[image]

**Edit**

I'm looking for a way to take this result of `st_overlaps()` and keep only those polygons that are inside the boundary (`balt`).

```
balt_tracts[st_overlaps(balt_tracts, balt) %>% lengths > 0,] %>% 
  tm_shape() + tm_polygons(col = "GEOID")
```

[image]

One thing I did notice is that `st_touches()` returns only three polygons. Is this a precision issue, or does this mean the census tract borders are not actually perfectly aligned with the larger polygon's borders?

```
 balt_tracts[st_touches(balt_tracts, balt) %>% lengths > 0,] %>% 
   tm_shape() + tm_polygons(col = "GEOID")
```

[image]

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663346/5977215) give you some ideas?

Comment: Hey @SymbolixAU, thanks for the link. It was an interesting post, but I think not relevant here. There, the OP wanted to split geometries that crossed a border and keep only the portions inside the border. Also, your there solution uses an `st_buffer()`, which I'm hoping to avoid here. See my edit for more detail. Maybe I am overthinking this, but I feel like there should be a simpler solution to my problem than the buffer I'm currently using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example, you should just supply a `county` argument to `get_acs()`, as Baltimore city is an independent entity:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tidycensus)
library(tigris)
library(tmap)

balt_tracts <- get_acs(geography = "tract",
                       variables = "B01003_001E", # population
                       year = 2018,
                       state = "Maryland",
                       county = "Baltimore city",
                       survey = "acs5",
                       geometry = TRUE) 

qtm(balt_tracts)
```

[image]

Your broader question is a worthwhile one, however.  If you *know* that your geometries align perfectly (as they will when using tigris/tidycensus for the same year, provided that `cb = TRUE` or `cb = FALSE` is used consistently), you can use `sf::st_filter()` with the `st_within` spatial predicate to do spatial subsetting.  For example, let's say we want to grab Census tracts in the Baltimore *metro area* (which is entirely in Maryland):

```
balt_metro <- core_based_statistical_areas(cb = TRUE, 
                                           year = 2018, 
                                           class = "sf") %>%
  filter(str_detect(NAME, "Baltimore"))

balt_metro_tracts <- tracts("MD", cb = TRUE, 
                            year = 2018, class = "sf") %>%
  st_filter(balt_metro, .predicate = st_within)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = balt_metro_tracts, fill = "white") + 
  geom_sf(data = balt_metro, fill = NA, color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kyle! Noted on the county argument. For `st_filter()`, this code is not returning the tracts that touch the Baltimore city boundary (which I got from `places()`), only the ones fully within the boundary: `balt_tracts %>% st_filter(balt, .predicate = st_within)`. Does this imply that the geometries are not perfectly aligned? That might explain the `st_touches()` and `st_overlaps()` results in my edit as well.

Comment: Yes it does imply that they aren't aligned.  The issue is that you are using the TIGER/Line file from tigris (with the default argument `cb = FALSE`) whereas tidycensus by default uses `cb = TRUE` and returns cartographic boundary files.  If you use `cb = TRUE` in your call to `places()` you'll get the expected result.  More broadly though - whereas tracts will nest cleanly within counties, they are not required to align with places so I'd just double-check your results when doing that sort of overlay.

Comment: ah, that did it. and noted on your point about places. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to turn each tract into a point and intersect on those, which removes the coincident borders that gave me trouble. This approach does not require choosing an arbitrary buffer distance like the one in the initial question.

`st_point_on_surface()` is preferable to `st_centroid()` since it guarantees the point will lie on the surface of the polygon, whereas some polygons will have centroids lying outside its surface.

```
balt_tracts[st_point_on_surface(balt_tracts)[balt,],] %>% 
  qtm()
```

[image]