# Identifying common borders of polygons using the Simple Features library from R

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I'm trying to identify the common borders of two different polygons using the `sf_intersection()` function from the `sf` package.

I tried this [simple approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760033/r-gis-identify-inner-borders-between-polygons-with-sf/47761959) in my data, which comes from a shapefile, but it's not working exactly as I expected.

My data is the shapefile names "zones" from [this repository](https://github.com/luisesanmartin/Share), and this is what I've tried:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

zones <- st_read('./Data/zones.shp')
zones$id <- seq(nrow(zones))
borders <- st_intersection(zones, zones)
borders <- borders[borders$id != borders$id.1, ]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = zones, color='red', fill=NA) +
  geom_sf(data = borders, color = 'navy')
```

The final plot yields this result:

[image]

If you look carefully, you'll note that there are some portions of the inner line of the polygons that are not part of the line in `borders` (they are red and not blue). 
I don't know why this is happening. Any hint or advice will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As @David_O mentions, the boundaries are not actually shared and therefore don't intersect. Try, for example: `ggplot(data = zones) +geom_sf() + xlim(c(768824.7, 770092.5)) + ylim(c(2944198.6, 2944940.3))` you will see a section where the two linestrings diverge.

Comment: You might try to `st_buffer` your zones object before intersecting.

Comment: The best thing I've ever used for repairing polygon lattices to fix up non-overlapping borders or overlapping slivers is: https://github.com/tudelft3d/pprepair - some assembly required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David_O identifies the issue - the POLYGON borders don't actually touch throughout the shared boundary so `st_intersection` won't identify them as such.

One workaround may be to `st_buffer` your zones object before intersecting, although this is admittedly a crude workaround:

```
borders <- st_intersection(st_buffer(zones, 5), st_buffer(zones, 5))

borders <- borders[borders$id != borders$id.1, ]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = zones, color='red', fill="transparent") +
  geom_sf(data = borders, color = 'navy')
```

Comment: That is a neat fix. A problem is that it will give you back a 10m wide POLYGON surrounding the border rather than a LINESTRING. Admittedly, I suspect you're already getting a Polygon or GeometryCollection. If this is just for display that may well work for you, but if you're after the border as a geometry for analytical purposes this may be an issue.

Comment: Great! indeed, using `st_buffer()` is a workaround to my issue

Comment: Hmm, yeah - I think it works okay for simple plotting but isn't very accurate. I think there is an `st_snap` solution. Let me investigate..

Comment: My attempts with `st_snap` have been returning GEOMETRYCOLLECTION with an odd polygon on one end. Unfortunately I'm not good enough with `sf` objects and the spatial predicates to understand why this is happening or how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

It is local imprecision in the borders. With most vector data formats, shared POLYGON borders are duplicated in each of the neighbours. It doesn't take very much for slight differences in the coordinates to make the intersection of the two borders incomplete.

That's not a solution, I'm afraid.

This section shows the kind of problem. The view window is:

```r
> par('usr')
[1]  764968.2  765650.8 2945266.2 2945890.9
```

[image: example gap]

That sliver is only about 3 metres wide.

EDIT: Just to add my attempt at a solution using `st_snap`. This seems to do the trick in some places but not consistently. It doesn't feel like it is working as intended. Also, just to note the projection uses US feet as units, which confused me.

```r
z1 <- st_geometry(zones[1,])
z2 <- st_geometry(zones[2,])

z1 <- st_cast(z1, 'LINESTRING')
z2 <- st_cast(z2, 'LINESTRING')

z1s <- st_snap(z1, z2, 1000)

border <- st_intersection(z1s, z2)
```

That snap tolerance is way over the top - the gaps between the zone seem to be < 10 feet - but even with this huge tolerance the actual border has missing sections. More oddly, the result has a totally unexpected extension that heads off >6500 feet from the actual intersection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the first idea that came into my mind when I saw the result. I'll try looking into a possible solution to this issue and will post it if I can find it.

Comment: I've played around with `st_snap` which my intuition says should snap the vertices of one polygon to another with a given tolerance, but it doesn't quite seem to work as I'm expecting